# ASP.NET Page load fires twice due to inline setting of background-image within repeater

Tags: asp.net, uri, repeater

Everything's running twice. I've got a repeater and I attempt to set a background-image within its ItemTemplate. I narrowed it down to the following line. as soon as I pull out the background-image... portion within the style attribute, it runs only once. The Photo is a data uri. It will actually show the background image if I leave the code in there, but causes everything to run twice. Oddly, if I put a space between the "url" and the "(" it also stops firing twice, but then the background image does not show as it breaks the required syntax for a background-image. I'm at a loss why it causes it to fire twice. I also tried variations, but same issue. Doesn't seem to have to do with the fact I'm using a data uri as I instead tried just a typical file.jpg and it still fired twice... I also pulled it out of the style attribute and put it in just a made believe attribute like test="" and it worked. So it seems to be a direct issue with binding to the css property "background-image: url(...)"

I even tried to move the code to the ItemDataBound event, and it still causes the page to run twice. I just can't figure this out.

```
<span style='<%# "background-image:url("+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Photo")+");height: 32px; width: 32px;background-size: 100%;background-position:0% 25%;background-repeat:no-repeat;"%>'></span>


<span style='background-image:url(<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Photo")%>);height: 32px; width: 32px;background-size: 100%;background-position:0% 25%;background-repeat:no-repeat;'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue had nothing to do with either ways I was attempting to display the image, it was due to some other items in the repeater not having a value for Photo, so it ended up yielding:

```
<span style='background-image:url("");height: 32px; width: 32px;background-size: 100%;background-position:0% 25%;background-repeat:no-repeat;'></span>
```

which left the URL of the background image empty. apparently this causes the browser to reload the page twice... from 2011 article: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2236-empty-src-and-url-values-can-cause-duplicate-page-requests.htm, it sounds like the empty url() gets interpreted as the page itself, thus causing the browser to load the page twice. Makes sense, but not sure why the browser doesn't interpret it differently to avoid this issue, i.e. can't reason why trying to load the page itself as a background image would ever be needed or wanted.